# How to detect URL in JS?

Tags: javascript

How do I detect a URL using javascript?

For example, if i have **mywebsite.com/video/r739cw3#1**, I want to execute a JS function that will convert this URL to a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `document.URL`

for Example

```
alert(document.URL);
```